# Extract & Display JSON Data from SQL Database Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sql, json, mariadb

I have a column (student_no) in my database with JSON data (String).

```
student No: [
     {First_name: 'John',
      Last_name: 'Wick',
      student_id: 1001,
     },
     {First_name: 'David',
      Last_name: 'Stone',
      student_id: 1002, 
     }
```

If I want to read and display only the `student_id = 1002` from the data, what is the right query?

I tried using `student_no.student_id = 1002` but there were error in the syntax. I want to access and display the `First_name`, `Last_name` by accessing the `student_id`.

Comment: What SQL RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using MariaDB.

Comment: In the json you have shown, student_no is an array. So index should be used to access the inner elements. student_no[1].student_id == 1002

Answer (score 2):

**With Javascript Code**

You can use [Javascript Array Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) (`.filter`) to solve that problem. Try this :

```js
function getSingleData(data, student_id) {
  return data.filter(d => d.student_id === student_id)[0];
}

let data = [ {First_name: 'John', Last_name: 'Wick', student_id: 1001, }, {First_name: 'David', Last_name: 'Stone', student_id: 1002, }];
console.log(getSingleData(data, 1002));
```

---

**With Maria DB Query**

I assume your table (`my_table`) is look like this :

| id | student_no |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [ { "First_name": "John", "Last_name": "Wick", "student_id": 1001 }, { "First_name": "David", "Last_name": "Stone", "student_id": 1002 } ] |

To get the data from column `student_no` which is an array of objects by `student_id`, just use the `JSON_TABLE` query like this :

```sql
SELECT j.*
FROM my_table m, JSON_TABLE(m.student_no, '$[*]' COLUMNS (
  First_name VARCHAR(50) path '$.First_name',
  Last_name VARCHAR(50) path '$.Last_name',
  student_id INT(11) path '$.student_id')) AS j
WHERE j.student_id = 1002;
```

The output will be :

| First_name | Last_name | student_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| David | Stone | 1002 |

**Notes: JSON_TABLE only works starts in [MariaDB 10.6.0](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_table)**

Answer (score 0):

JSON data cannot be parsed with a `SELECT`statement.  You'll need to query your desired columns with `SELECT` (including the JSON column) but then to use the `JSON_EXTRACT` function. Check out [this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/working-with-json-in-mysql) for a good examples of working with JSON data in MySQL.

Comment: Fixed broken link.